# Apple TV how to download apps

Tags: itunes

I am senior, just purchased and hooked up the Apple TV, was trying to download the German TV stations but found them but was not able to open them up, it keeps saying enter your I tune password...I thought having a password for Apple goes across all accounts and I finished my account information.  Do I need to pay for the German channels, willing to do that but I am confused my apple account should be my account information across and my apple id and password? I have no interest in music so why should I have a password for my Itune account?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  You need to use your Apple ID with that device.  I'm guessing from your question that you might need a more in-depth guide to how to use the Apple TV (more than you can get from this site).  Take a look at [this guide from iMore](http://www.imore.com/apple-tv-ultimate-guide), it might help answer some of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different German TV apps as far as I can see.
They are both available to download for free.

As for the Apple ID and iTunes account confusion; maybe this will help. I've taken a photo of my Apple ID for you:

[image]

[image]

Now I've censored the beginning of the email addresses, but you can see that I have more than one account associated with my **Apple ID**; one for ***iCloud***, one for ***iTunes***, and one for ***Game Centre***.

Most people probably use the same account for everything. And you probably do too. So when it asks for your iTunes password, it's probably the exact same one that you've already provided.

Also; your iTunes account is not just for downloading music. It's also for downloading apps, movies & TV shows, and more (like virtual books and podcasts).

I hope this helps, and if you have any follow up questions, feel free to ask.